# How to write the unit test for test apollo useQuery in vuejs3

Tags: vue.js, unit-testing, jestjs, vuejs3, vue-apollo

I have a problem with the unit test. I try to check `useQuery` that has been called with `toHaveBeenCalledTimes()` but no luck it always returns zero time. I'm not sure which part I mistake.

```js
export default defineComponent({
  name: 'MyComponent',
  setup() {
    const {
      result: dataPagination
    } = useQuery(GET_DATA_PAGINATION, {
      skip: pagination.skip,
      take: pagination.take,
    });

    // another part...
  },
});
```

And spec.ts just like this

```js
const mockUseQuery = jest.fn();

jest.mock('@vue/apollo-composable', () => ({
  useQuery: () => ({
    result: mockUseQuery
  })
}));

describe('StoreType.vue', () => {
  let wrapper = null;

  beforeEach(() => {
    config = {
      global: {
        ...config.global,
      },
    };
    wrapper = mount(MyComponent, { ...config,
      shallow: true
    });
  });


  afterEach(() => {
    wrapper.unmount();
    jest.resetAllMocks();
  });

  it('Fetch all store type by pagination', async() => {
    expect(wrapper.exists()).toBe(true);
    expect(mockQuery).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);
  });
});
```